# Keep only one repository in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, build, artifactory

I have a problem where we have copying our builds to Artifactory. But due to storage issue we need to keep only one build artifact. When a new build artifact is uploaded, the previous one should automatically get deleted.

I tried searching for solutions but could not find any. Solutions i.e., plugin, available config, or cron job, any of them are acceptable.

Thanks in advance for the help

Expecting a Solution

Answer (score 0):

You can configure build retention using this [REST API](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/control-build-retention?tocId=kOZYsdY3ryX1rqXc%7ERhvYA).
You can also [control](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/example?tocId=Z_YF5QgCdCFjkt5Uj3l0Eg) this using the JFrog CLI build-discard/bdi commands.

If you need additional cleanup, you can find additional plugins and cleanup methods [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-cleanup-methods-how-do-i-delete-old-artifacts/artifactory-cleanup-methods-how-do-i-delete-old-artifacts) which can help you save storage.

Comment: jf rt bdi my-build-name --max-builds= 10
This command seems suitable for my requirement but I need to run rest call, I could not find the corresponding rest api

Comment: WDYM? I just provided one to you, both by client and REST API.